# What good, reliable and simple body camera straps are there?

Tags: camera-straps

I've been searching for a few hours. I am looking for a strap that doesn't have:

- Leather end-straps (will break after heavy use)
- Buckles
- Thin-end attachments (Peak Design-type attachments)
- BlackRapid-type system
- Neoprene (itchy/annoying for the skin)

What I am looking for is:

- Long strap, wearable on the side (about 55-60")
- Made of webbing and/or nylon
- Nylon attachments

Basically, similar to the Peak Design Sling or Leash, but without the thin attachments and nylon attachments instead. I can't believe this isn't easily found.

Comment: To what particular camera do you want to attach a strap? What kind of strap lugs/connectors are built into the camera?

Comment: Why do you think neoprene pads are itchy/annoying for the skin? They aren't solid neoprene like a disposable neoprene glove, but are rather made from a textile that has neoprene woven into the fibers.

Comment: You have awfully specific requirements that, as you have noticed, don't seem to be entirely met by the market. Perhaps this is an excellent DIY opportunity, or maybe even a crowdfunding opportunity? =)

Comment: @Michael Clark D5500 with a kg more from from a large lens and flash. Standard strap lugs you see on almost all DSLRs.

Comment: @scottbb I would say that it's awfully simple (one piece, about 60", webbing). However, it seems camera gear companies are too busy coming up with complex systems with buckles and other gadgets, that there is no one making just a straight up long a simple one-piece strap.

Comment: @samseva Swivel lugs with triangular or circular rings such as found on Nikon's pro bodies (D7300, D750, D3, D4, D5, etc) and older pro and amateur SLRs are markedly different from Canon's stationary slot lugs across their entire DSLR line that are similar to what you see on Nikon's mid level  (D5x00) and entry level (D3x00) bodies, which differ from other's...

Comment: I don't disagree that what you're asking for is *simple*. But you have a series of very specific requirements. The length requirement alone eliminates just about *every* strap on the market. Gear and accessory makers are trying to accommodate the middle 2-3 sigma of the market distribution. It's evident by what they put out that they *believe* the market wants adjustability (buckles, etc.), style (leather), comfort (neoprene, wider straps), or that "pro quick draw" function and appearance (BlackRapid-syle). And it appears they believe that 30"-40" ought to be enough, for at least 95% of users.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with any strap that meets all of your requirements. The trend over the past few years is to move away from one piece straps, such as those supplied with cameras, to modular systems that allow each user the flexibility of setting up a strap in different ways for different use cases and shooting situations. Neoprene has become a popular material for use in the shoulder pads for most straps. I'm not sure why you think pads that use neoprene would be uncomfortable or irritate the skin. This isn't the same form of neoprene that you would encounter, for instance, with a neoprene disposable glove. The neoprene is incorporated into the fibers that are woven to make the pad's external material. Most people find neoprene pads much more comfortable than webbing or foam.

About the closest I think you are going to come to what you seek is to use something like the OP/Tech [Super Classic Strap](http://optechusa.com/straps/super-classic-strap.html) or [Utility Strap](http://optechusa.com/straps/utility-strap.html) with the [3/8" webbing connector](http://optechusa.com/system-connectors/3-8-webbing-connectors.html) option. The [Super Classic Strap - Bino](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JJGWVI) (you'll need to click on the "Bino" style option) includes the 3/8" webbing connectors without the quick detach connectors on either end of the pad and is adjustable from 23" to 67" long. You can check out [this video](https://youtu.be/QkhQL9rty-8) that describes various ways to attach a 3/8" webbing connector.

Having used the OP/TEch system for years I can vouch that their products are rock solid reliable and I've never had a failure of any kind with any of their stuff. I will say that the 3/8" webbing connectors will, just like the straps supplied with Nikon and Canon cameras with 3/8" webbing ends, eventually show wear at the point where they loop through the camera's attachment lugs and need to be replaced periodically. (In my experience after 3-4 years of fairly heavy use). The [Pro Loop](http://optechusa.com/system-connectors/pro-loop-connector.html) connectors are more durable and are made from 1/4" tubular nylon parachute cord rated to support well over 100 pounds. I have yet to see any Pro Loop or [Uni-Loop](http://optechusa.com/system-connectors/uni-loop.html) connector (a version of the same connector with quick detach connectors on the camera end) I've used show any sign of wear at all. I use both a version of the Op/Tech Utility Strap that was supplied to me several years ago by Canon Professional Services and an Op/Tech Double Sling. I've also got various 3/8" webbing, Pro Loop, and Uni-Loop connectors in different sizes that allow me to build a customized modular system for whatever a particular shoot requires.

On a typical three camera shoot I'll have a gripped 7D Mark II + EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II and a gripped 5D Mark III + 24-105mm f/4 IS or 24-70mm f/2.8 L hanging from either side of the Double Sling and a 5D Mark II with EF 17-40mm f/4 L or a fast prime hanging around my neck by the Utility strap. That's roughly $11K worth of gear I'm trusting to the Op/Tech system. Sometimes there are also flashes or wireless flash controllers attached to the camera's hot shoes as well. I've never worried about the Op/Tech system coming apart. The system does have redundant connectors attached to either both camera lugs or one lug plus the grip's strap loop connector on the cameras attached to the Double Sling. If one should fail the other would still fully secure the camera to the sling.

Comment: I've had first hand experience with neoprene traps back in the day when I used to play the saxophone. The OP/Tech looks like a solid company though.

Comment: Those early neoprene straps were kind of like stretchy foam. The newer types have a textured surface that let them breathe a bit more. Some of the Op/Tech straps (like my CPS branded Utility Strap) can be flipped over and worn with the fabric side on the top that's normally facing up facing down against the skin instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Simplr's F1 strap](https://simplr.us/product/f1-camera-strap/) would fit your wishes (although the answer is a bit late). I just find them too expensive for such a simple strap! Otherwise they seem to be nice.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to Photo.SE. That does look like a nice strap. According to the specs, the strap's standard 36"–56" length doesn't meet OP's length requirement. But the specs also mention "customs lengths available — please inquire", so it is indeed an option.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple camera strap, I like Couch Guitar Straps. In particular, their [recycled seatbelt straps](https://www.couchguitarstraps.com/camera-straps/seatbelt-camera-straps.html).

The seatbelt material is nice, pretty lightweight and flexible, but seems strong enough. It easily slides on your shoulder as you lift the camera up. As it's fairly wide, it helps spread the weight of the camera on your shoulder. The length can be adjusted, so it is long enough to wear across your body, messenger bag style.

The attachments for the camera are fairly thick, seems they should last a while. Personally I use it with Peak Design Anchor Links, they make it quick and easy to remove the strap, or switch to another strap as required. But you can use the regular attachments if you want.

The Couch straps are available in a variety of colours, so you can get something bright, or more subtle if you prefer. They also have some nice 'hippie weave' designs. All of the Couch straps are vegan, no leather parts.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice find. If only they would make them longer.

Answer (score 1):

Neoprene straps are popular because they increase comfort and reduce strain on the users muscles and joints.  That said, it seems you just need to **buy a roll of webbing and sew the strap to the desired specifications yourself.**  Don't forget to sear the ends of the webbing so it doesn't come unraveled.

Answer (score 1):

When climbing, my camera strap rig was Dyneema girth hitched to each lug (something like this: https://www.rei.com/product/899001/black-diamond-10mm-dynex-runner) and a modified gear sling attached to each of those (https://www.rei.com/product/620114/metolius-multi-loop-contour-gear-sling).

Dyneema and webbing ain't going anywhere. This is what we call, bomb-proof.

Answer (score 0):

My favorites over the years were:

- Domke 1" Strap ( easy to fold, non-conspicuous, nylon, with rubber
  embroidery for better grip on the shoulder)
- Spyder Camera Holster (stainless steel lock mounted on a belt, camera
  hangs on your hip, is easily accessible and the system can
  comfortably hold 5D body with 70-200 lens with less fatigue
  than ordinary strap)
- Leica strap (quite ordinary, non-conspicuous,
  nylon, relatively easy to fold)

These are not long enough for your requirements though. I wear cameras usually on my shoulder.